# What would cause a Windows user account to report having been created at a later date than it was last logged into?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, user-accounts

Based on my parsing of registry keys, this Windows user account was created *after* it was last logged into. Obviously this is inaccurate, but what might cause this?

Comment: Have you considered bad time sync?

Comment: Nothing; Could cause it.  I would suspect your parsing of the registry hive more then anything.